# how to write double queries from one table in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have 2 kind of devices to work on number of points for each day.
I want to get the current, average and also maximum points in each day.

The table structure is similar to:

```
working_date           device    point_number
2020-03-12                A         1
2020-03-12                A         2 
2020-03-12                B         3 
2020-03-12                B         4
2020-03-14                A         5 
2020-03-14                A         6
2020-03-16                B         7
2020-03-17                A         8
2020-03-17                B         9
```

Each row representatives 1 point. First thing first, I have created query to show number of points and device for each date

```
select working_date, count(distinct device), count(point_number) from table1 group by working_date order by working_date
```

and it resulted:

```
working_date    points_qty        device_qty       
2020-03-12         4                 2
2020-03-14         2                 1
2020-03-16         1                 1
2020-03-17         2                 2
```

Choosing 2020-03-18 as the report date, I want to get the last working_date which is 2020-03-17 and I want to get the current point that being done on that day and maximum points that being done by the device/point/day.

The current qty is the result from points_qty / device_qty, while the maximum points is the maximum points from all working_date
The desired result:

```
report_date    last_working_date    current_point_qty      maximum_qty
2020-03-18      2020-03-17                  1                 4
```

I am lost at writing the full query to get the desired results. How should I write my query for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to create multiple `SELECT` and use `JOIN` to merge them, so each `SELECT` would have its own scope and filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have used group by working_date in my previous answer aggregation will be based on that group by. In this answer I have done the same thing with window function so that the select statement is no more tied with the group by clause. Though all the aggregation is partitioned by working_date but to find overall average I didn't use partition by clause to get average on all the rows:

```
 select (working_date::date + '1 day'::interval) report_date,working_date, 
   sum(countdevice)over(partition by working_date)/sum(countnumber)over(partition by working_date) current_point_qty,   
   max(countnumber) over(partition by working_date),avg(countnumber/countdevice)over(order by (select 1))
   maximum_qty from (
    select  working_date, count(distinct device)countdevice, 
    count(point_number)countnumber  from table1 group by working_date order by working_date )t
    order by working_date desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     select (working_date::date + '1 day'::interval) report_date,working_date, 
   sum(countdevice)/sum(countnumber) current_point_qty,   max(countnumber) 
   maximum_qty from (
    select  working_date, count(distinct device)countdevice, 
    count(point_number)countnumber  from table1 group by working_date order by working_date )t
    group by (working_date::date + '1 day'::interval),working_date
    order by working_date desc limit 1
```

Comment: Thankyou! What if I also want to get the overall average point that being done?

Comment: You are welcome. Average on countnumber? avg(countnumber) will do the trick.

Comment: I want to get the overall average of the current_qty.  In this case, (4 / 2 = 2) + (2 / 1 = 2) + (1 / 1 = 1) + (2 / 2 = 1) = 1,5. How I supposed to write my query in order to get the desired result?

Comment: I have posted another answer which will also display the overall average.